# Spring roo - telling dbmanaged entities to remove the "Id" suffix from the foreign key method name

Tags: spring-roo

Spring roo creates foreign key entities like this:

In the Contact_Roo_DbManaged.aj

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "CONTACT_ID", referencedColumnName = "CONTACT_ID")
private Contact Booking.contactId;

public Contact Booking.getContactId() {
    return contactId;
}

public void Booking.setContactId(Contact contactId) {
    this.contactId = contactId;
}
```

In the table, the field name is CONTACT_ID but in my java objects I don't want to see the Id on the end of the name because it is actually returning a Contact object.  Is there a way to get around this other than pulling in every join column and redefining the variable name?  I did not have this issue with hibernate tools as it automatically remove the Id from the end of the field name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently there isn't any automatic way to customize reverse engineering. It seems a good improvement, please create the request at https://jira.springsource.org/browse/ROO